# Generic TypeOf operator?

Tags: vb.net, typeof, generics, generic-type-argument

```
Dim x = GetType(List(Of )) 'valid statement
Dim list As New List(Of String)
```

Now I want to see if `list` is a `List(Of T)` variable:

```
Dim isList = TypeOf list Is List(Of )
```

On the last line I get a compile error: "Type Expected".

Is there any cheap-performance `TypeOf` operator alternative for generics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to do this with reflection:

```
Dim type = list.[GetType]()
Dim isList = type.IsGenericType AndAlso
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(List(Of ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

You need to call `GetType()` and check `IsGenericType` and `GetGenericTypeDefinition`.

Answer (score 1):

See Hanselman's blog: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheVBEquivalentToCTypeofKeyword.aspx

GetType(T) - it is that simple :).

Comment: Doh, Apologies. OP is testing for the parameterized list type. I hit this QA looking for a typeof(T) equivalent, so if anyone else is misdirected like me...